# css hover color transition loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-web-developer

I want to create a hover color transition but I want it to keep a loop of it. I was yellow transition to red then back to yellow and so on.

I am unable to figure out how to loop it. Do I need to add javascript to it? If so how?

https://jsfiddle.net/hg4s0tmp/1/

```
    body {
        background-color: #FF0;
        padding: 15x;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
}

    body:hover {
        background-color: #AD310B;
        -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
        -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
        transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
        animation-iteration-count: 3;

}
```

Comment: Are you actually using [Microsoft Visual Web Developer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/visual-web-developer-2010-express-has-arrived/)? That was last released in 2010? Really?

Comment: Also, please include the HTML and any JavaScript you're using in the question, not just on an external site like jsfiddle.net. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to produce a runnable example using an interface much like jsFiddle's. I know you've already got your answer, but Stack Overflow is more about helping everyone with the same question as you, so please help those people by improving your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use CSS [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) with keyframes for an infinite loop, rather than the `transition` property. Here's an example:

```css
div {
  background-color: pink;
}

div:hover {
  animation: change-color 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes change-color {
  0% {
    background-color: pink;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hover me</div>
```